# Computer freezes on startup

Tags: 20.04, freeze, wacom

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, a fresh install.

I installed all of the latest updates, and now when the computer is starting up, it shows a black screen with the mouse visible, but is entirely unresponsive. The only thing that could have affected it was that I installed the linuxwacom driver (that maps buttons to Xinput events) and then shut down.
Starting back up, it does exactly what I described above.

Please help!

Thanks!

EDIT 1:
I *can* access the motherboard's BIOS. (By holding the power button for 4 seconds)
[image]

Comment: I will check. I doubt it is a hardware problem, as I didnt touch the computer and it worked perfectly until about 15 minutes ago

Comment: Also, to be clear, I see the system splash first and then it goes to a black screen. I am fairly sure its software thats broken.

Comment: Ok that is an important distinction so thanks for clarifying.  Were you able to access a root shell prompt from GRUB?

Comment: No, grub didn't open (press and hold shift, press and hold escape, each of the fX keys, nothing worked)

Comment: To diagnose this further,  I suggest that you create USB installation media and run a live session (Try Ubuntu) and see if that loads and if you can access the file system

Comment: I am in a live session now and can access the file system.

Comment: If you are savvy enough to chroot into your installed system from the live session, you can try to undo the actions that you believe led to the current problem. Otherwise make sure that your backups are in order and reinstall the operating system.

Comment: I reinstalled, no biggie (3rd reinstall this week tho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, here is what I did:
Create an installation media with Ubuntu.
Live boot into that media, and connect to the internet.
Enter your file system, and upload your files to the cloud (Google Drive, DropBox, etc).
Run the install, and follow the instructions.

NOTE: This *will* erase your operating system and reinstall it! Proceed only if you know what you are doing. You, and only you, can take responsibility for losing files. I am posting this to assist, but I am not a computer expert, just a dude who knows his way around Linux.
I will not take responsibility for loss of your files. If you don't think you are savvy enough to follow the above steps without breaking something, find someone who is.